# Regarding Java for-each additional variable declaration

Tags: java, foreach

in normal for loop, we could do multiple variable declarations & limit their scope within the loop

eg: if I have an ArrayList myList of

```
for(int i=0, j=5 ; i <myList.size() ; i++, j--)
```

now i & j's are limited to loops scope

Can we do something similar with for-each  // limit scope to loop & also change its value each iteration

```
for (Integer value : myList) {
}
```

Comment: Not and limit their scope to the loop, no. If you need `for` loop functionality, use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
int j = 5;
for (Integer value : myList) {
  i++; j--;
  // Code
}
```

you will still have access to them in the scope outside the for, but you can't initialize them inside the for either :/

Comment: You should be incrementing i and decrementing j after running your code, otherwise it doesn't match the `for` loops execution. That said, since `i` is simply being used as an index to access elements of the list, it may not be needed in the `foreach` loop at all.

Comment: @Christian I wanted to limit scope of j within loop

Comment: @Anish, you could just put his answer inside of { } braces if you limit the scope of i and j but there is no way to do this within the enhanced `for` loop itself.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, with the enhanced for loop you are bound to the (hidden) iterator form.
So you can't keep the variables scope inside the loop and modify it since you can't use the `static` modifier for local variables in java. The best thing you can do is described in Christian's answer. (Or fall back to the basic for loop)